# Tkinter и функция заливки с затравкой

Tags: python, графика, tkinter, рекурсия

В общем. Имеется подключенный модуль Tkinter для работы с примитивами. Сама программа представляет собой холст с расположенными на ней рядом стоящие квадраты, образующие собой координатную сетку (масштабная модель пикселей экрана). Все квадраты помещены в двумерный кортеж. На этой сетке произвольная фигура,которую необходимо закрасить используя алгоритм заливки с затравкой.

Если вдруг кто-то не знает,что это:выбирается затравочный пиксель,принадлежащий области закрашивания. Идет проверка, является ли он границей фигуры. Если нет, то окрашивается, а 4 пикселя вокруг него встают в очередь на проверку.

Есть два метода:рекурсия и искусственный стек.С последним я возиться не стал и придумал ему замену.Написал функции.Обе вроде логичные.Но ни одна не работает корректно.

В чем проблема?

```
def zatravka(x,y):
    if canvas.itemcget(squads[x+16,16-y],option='fill')!='blue':
        canvas.itemconfig(squads[x+16,16-y],fill='red')
        zatravka(x+1,y)
        zatravka(x-1,y)
        zatravka(x,y+1)
        zatravka(x,y-1)
```

Поясню,что не работает тут.От пикселя затравки закрашивается полоска до границы.Далее идет зацикливание:спускается на строку "zatravka(x-1,y)",и снова прыгает на "zatravka(x+1,y)".И так,пока я не получу переполнение.

```
def zatravka(x,y):
    ox=[]
    oy=[]
    i=0
    ox.append(x)
    oy.append(y)
    while 1:
        if canvas.itemcget(squads[x+16,16-y],option='fill')!='blue':
            canvas.itemconfig(squads[x+16,16-y],fill='red')

            ox.append(x+1)
            oy.append(y)

            ox.append(x-1)
            oy.append(y)

            ox.append(x)
            oy.append(y+1)

            ox.append(x)
            oy.append(y-1)
        i=i+1
        if i==len(ox)+1:break
```

Окрашивает затравочный пиксель,4 пикселя вокруг него и стоит.Если закрыть окно с холстом,то в интерпретатор пойдет ошибка:

> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".39114160"

Comment: Эмъ... По первому варианту - А что такое "x+16,16-y"? Не работал с tkinter, может быть вы выходите за границы области отрисовки и поэтому не можете установить там цвет? А раз там цвета нет, то пытаетесь установить ему цвет - вот и прыгает.

По второму варианту - а где у вас x или y меняется? Странно что закрашивает что-то еще кроме первого пикселя.

Comment: Хе-хе...

Если не равно синему, то закрасить красным)) Вот и зацикливается) Вы еще проверку на то, что уже закрасили добавьте)

Comment: @BOPOH.
По первому.Есть массив 31х31.Оси проходят ровно по середине для отображения отрезка (-15,15) по обеим осям.Пользователь вводит любые координаты:отрицательные и/или положительные.В этой формуле они переводятся в индексы.Все квадраты белые.Кроме границ,разумеется.Они синие.
По второму.Меняется тут
    ox.append(x+1)
    oy.append(y)
    ox.append(x-1)
    oy.append(y)
    ox.append(x)
    oy.append(y+1)
    ox.append(x)
    oy.append(y-1)
Координаты наращиваются равномерно.Чтобы при доступе к ним через i выдавало верные координаты с обеих списков.

А вот про проверку,спасибо.Попробую

Comment: Ой,как некрасиво отформатировалось.

Comment: @BOPOH,спасибо вам большое.Ваша идея с дополнительной проверкой оказалась верна!Вставил ее в рекурсию вторым условием,и всё заработало!

Comment: @Семён Сигунава, вы сами посмотрите вторую функцию - проверка идет по squads[x+16,16-y]. А откуда эти x и y берутся? Возможно вы просто неудачно скопипастили свою функцию - проверьте все ли верно.

И в любом случае стоит проверять выход за границы, вдруг часть фигуры скрылась за границей?

И избегайте погружений - потом пригодится )

    def zatravka(x,y):
        if is_outside_screen(...):
            return
        if is_border(...):
            return

        fill_color(...)
        zatravka(x+1,y)
        zatravka(x-1,y)
        zatravka(x,y+1)
        zatravka(x,y-1)

Comment: @BOPOH,функции я ниоткуда не копипастил.Мог только ошибиться,когда писал,опираясь на псевдокод.

А x и y вводятся с клавиатуры.

По поводу выхода за границы.В этом я смысла не увидел,так как надо вписать координаты точки,принадлежащей области фигуры.Такие тонкости были излишни.Это лабораторная работа по комп.графике.Тут цель - демонстрация алгоритма заливки.

Фигура отрисована изначально внутри границы.Она статична и не изменяется.

Но,спасибо за советы.На будущее учту=)